# Scikit BinaryClassification training data selection

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm training a BinaryClassifier on data that has 100 attributes where the positive scenario occurs only 3% of 800k items. During training, do we need to include the positives as well as the negatives instances? I'm guessing that we shouldnt as the outcome would only be binary i.e. if the model is trained on positives, then a weak match would mean that it's negative.

If in case i do need to include both then would the pandas DataFrame's sample method be reliable?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to handle an imbalanced dataset, there are many blog posts online on that topic, e.g. [here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/03/imbalanced-classification-problem/). One possible way to use pandas' sample method would be to set the [`weights`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) parameter to the frequency of the other class, i.e. 0.97 for positive instances and 0.03 for negative ones, thereby correcting the imbalance by oversampling.

But if you're saying that you could theoretically fit a model to the distribution of the positive instances and, during testing, label all outliers as negative instances – that is possible, although not advisable. That approach would certainly perform worse than one that learns from both classes. Furthermore, binary classification algorithms like scikit-learn's always assume instances from both classes.

Answer (score -1):

If you are training a binary classifier you will need to have two outputs in your training dataset.

At least if you want your classifier to work.

What you have is an unbalanced dataset, here are some ways to address this problem:

https://machinelearningmastery.com/tactics-to-combat-imbalanced-classes-in-your-machine-learning-dataset/

Comment: "If you are training a binary classifier you will need to have two outputs in your training dataset." is not really true, and also not what the question refers to, I think. It's common to just output the probability of the positive class.